# Getting error while trying to Deploy in heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

Getting error while trying to Deploy in heroku

```
remote:        ------------------------------
remote:        Bundle completed (48.81s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError:     Can't load WDM!
remote:  !
remote:  !     WDM is not supported on your system. For a cross-platform alternative,
remote:  !     we recommend using Listen: http://github.com/guard/listen
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/lib/wdm.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/lib/wdm.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_23f08682e6a066ec3fbe1f3ee37ee97d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote:  !     Caused by:
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- wdm_ext
```

Comment: it clearly says `ensure you can run \`$ bundle exec rake -P\``. did you try it?

Comment: how can i ensure that? im using windows system if that makes any difference

Comment: just run it like `bundle exec rake -P`

Comment: it does work when i run it manually , but it still gives me the same error when pushing to heroku.

Comment: so it says `WDM is not supported on your system. For a cross-platform alternative,  we recommend using Listen: http://github.com/guard/listen`. and  yes it is because they fon't have windows.

Answer (score 1):

From the description provided it seems like you have specified a wdm dependency since you were developing  the application on windows but the same could not be found when deploying on heroku(unix system) .

Have you added the following in the Gemfile??

```
platforms :mswin do 
  gem "wdm"
end
```

If it is there in Gemfile then modify it to below mentioned:

```
platforms :mswin do 
  gem "wdm", :group => [:development]
end
```

Then add it to git and try deploying on heroku.